# `pivot_longer` operation - simpler way of achieving the expected output?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a `df` of the form:

```
df <- tibble(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  val02 = c(0,1,0),
  val03 = c(1,0,0),
  val04 = c(0,1,1),
  age02 = c(1,2,3),
  age03 = c(2,3,4),
  age04 = c(3,4,5)
)
```

I want to bring it into tidy format like:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
     id year    val   age
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 02        0     1
2     1 03        1     2
3     1 04        0     3
4     2 02        1     2
5     2 03        0     3
6     2 04        1     4
7     3 02        0     3
8     3 03        0     4
9     3 04        1     5
```

---

Using two seperate `pivot_longer` manipulations with a `left_join` at the end I achieved what I want:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("val"), names_to = "year", values_to = "val", names_prefix = "val")
df2 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("age"), names_to = "year", values_to = "age", names_prefix = "age")

left_join(df1, df2) %>%
  select(id, year, val, age)
```

This, however, seems utterly complicated.

*How can I simplify this operation? Is there a way to perform this operation in one go? (in one pipe..?)*

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the complexity of your strings (column names), but to give an idea:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-id,
               names_to = c('.value', 'year'),
               names_pattern = '([a-z]+)(\\d+)'
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
     id year    val   age
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 02        0     1
2     1 03        1     2
3     1 04        0     3
4     2 02        1     2
5     2 03        0     3
6     2 04        1     4
7     3 02        0     3
8     3 03        0     4
9     3 04        1     5
```