# `pivot_longer` operation with different naming schemes

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a `df` of the form:

```
df <- tibble(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  x02val_a = c(0,1,0),
  x03val_a = c(1,0,0),
  x04val_a = c(0,1,1),
  x02val_b = c(0,2,0),
  x03val_b = c(1,3,0),
  x04val_b = c(0,1,2),
  age02 = c(1,2,3),
  age03 = c(2,3,4),
  age04 = c(3,4,5)
)
```

I want to bring it into tidy format like:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
     id year    val_a   val_b   age
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 02          0       0       1
2     1 03          1       2       2
...
```

The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686548/pivot-longer-operation-simpler-way-of-achieving-the-expected-output) worked for simpler naming schemes. With the naming scheme present in my real dataset, however, I struggle to define a regex that matches all patterns.

My attempts so far all missed one or the other schemes. I can grab the one with the variable name first and the year last (`age02`) or the one with the type and year first and the name last (`x02var`) but not both at the same time.

Is there a way to do this with a) a regex? or b) some combinations or parameterizations of the `pivot_longer` call(s)?

*I know there is always the possibility to do it with a left join at the end as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686548/pivot-longer-operation-simpler-way-of-achieving-the-expected-output)*

---

I tried to define the regex with two groups inside each other (since the groups are not strictly serial [meaning: left, right], which led me to):

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-id,names_to = c('.value', 'year'),names_pattern = '([a-z]+(\\d+)[a-z]+_[a-z])')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try. It seems this name pattern works:

```r
> df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-id,
                  names_to = c('.value', 'year','.value'),
                  names_pattern = '([a-z]+)(\\d+)([a-z_]*)')
# A tibble: 9 x 5
     id year  xval_a xval_b   age
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 02         0      0     1
2     1 03         1      1     2
3     1 04         0      0     3
4     2 02         1      2     2
5     2 03         0      3     3
6     2 04         1      1     4
7     3 02         0      0     3
8     3 03         0      0     4
9     3 04         1      2     5
```

Comment: The idea to define a regex with three groups, of which some might be missing in some names, did the trick for me. Thx

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit roundabout, but because of the inconsistent name style, you might first rename your columns to match an easier pattern. There are 3 possible pieces of information in your names, but (at least in your example) each column has only 2 of these.

The relevant pieces are:

- Multiple continuous matches to `"[a-z_]"`, which either occurs after "x" or after the 2 digits. Whichever of these is present will get moved to the beginning of the name; whichever is *not* present will just not return anything and not take up any space.
- 2 digits, which get moved to the end.

The parameterization possible with `pivot_longer`'s `".value"` option gives you column names in just one step based on this cleaner pattern. Should be trivial enough to adjust the pattern as needed, e.g. to fit a different number of digits.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rename_all(stringr::str_replace, "x?([a-z_]*)(\\d{2})([a-z_]*)", "\\1\\3\\2") %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c(".value", "year"), names_pattern = "([a-z_]+)(\\d{2})")
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>      id year  val_a val_b   age
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 02        0     0     1
#> 2     1 03        1     1     2
#> 3     1 04        0     0     3
#> 4     2 02        1     2     2
```